# How can we set all references to null associated with an object in java?

Tags: java, object, memory, reference, garbage-collection

I have N reference to an java object. I wanted to set all reference pointing to this object as null. I don't know how many references are pointing to this object.

Comment: "I don't know how many references are pointing to this object." if you don't have access to all this references then you can't. Anyway this question seems like [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe describe why you think you want to do it and maybe someone will suggest some better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which is specifically not possible in Java and most other modern languages. If it were, it would be a very dangerous thing to do which could break the invariants of other objects, like collections containing your object (for example, if a hash table contained it as a key).

However, if you want to ensure that an expensive object goes away promptly when you want it to, there is a simple pattern you can use to ensure this.

```
// This could also be some built-in class rather than one you write
class ExpensiveObject {
    // ... fields holding giant arrays, external resources, etc etc go here ...

    void someOperation() {
        // ... code ...
    }
}

class ExpensiveObjectHolder {
    ExpensiveObject target;

    ExpensiveObjectHolder(ExpensiveObject target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    void someOperation() {
        if (target == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "This ExpensiveObject has been deleted.");
        } else {
            target.someOperation();
        }
        // You can also omit this if/else and just let target.someOperation()
        // throw NullPointerException, but that might be annoying to debug.
    }

    void delete() {
        target = null;
    }
}
```

Then you create the wrapper around the object:

```
ExpensiveObjectHolder h = new ExpensiveObjectHolder(new ExpensiveObject());
```

and when you want it to go away, you do:

```
h.delete();
```

and since `target` was the *only* reference to the `ExpensiveObject`, which is now gone, we know that it is now garbage and will be discarded when the garbage collector notices.

---

Further notes:

It might be useful to make the `ExpensiveObject` and `ExpensiveObjectHolder` implement the same interface, but this can also make it easier to forget to use the holder where it should be.

If the `ExpensiveObject` has methods which do something like `return this;`, make sure that the method in the holder returns the holder instead.